# Extract a dataframe from two dataframes matching the same values for a column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames of different length. I want to extract out the data where the values of 'key1' are the same for both the data frames.

```
In [6]: data1['key1'][5:10]
Out[6]: 
5    3701061.280649
6    3702854.401078
7    3706447.681452
8    3710048.323744
9    3713648.507167
Name: key1, dtype: float64

In [7]: data2['key1'][10:15]
Out[7]: 
10    3735249.951436
11    3738850.242555
12    3742450.472855
13    3746051.017456
14    3749651.185752
Name: key1, dtype: float64
```

I basically want to end up with two data frames from each data1 and data2, so I can plot out the differences for 'key2'(y-axis) for 'key1'(x-axis)

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: So you want something like `data1[data.key1 == data2.key1]` and vice versa?

Comment: Yes, exactly BUT my len(data1) and len(data2) is not the same.

Comment: OK updated my answer, you can use `isin` to filter out the df rows, I've added dummy data to illustrate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `isin`, this will filter out the values of your column that are in the column values from the other df and then repeat for the other way round:

```
In [4]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':arange(10), 'b':randn(10)})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':arange(2,12), 'b':randn(10)})
print(df)
print(df1)
   a         b
0  0 -0.255545
1  1 -1.550302
2  2 -0.825056
3  3  1.475839
4  4  0.059035
5  5  2.295766
6  6  1.604147
7  7 -1.877267
8  8 -0.462598
9  9 -1.347194
    a         b
0   2 -1.462567
1   3 -0.277680
2   4 -0.461539
3   5  1.094466
4   6 -1.086069
5   7  0.249207
6   8  2.613443
7   9  1.036450
8  10 -0.562149
9  11 -0.679488
In [6]:

df[df.a.isin(df1.a)]
Out[6]:
   a         b
2  2 -0.825056
3  3  1.475839
4  4  0.059035
5  5  2.295766
6  6  1.604147
7  7 -1.877267
8  8 -0.462598
9  9 -1.347194
In [7]:

df1[df1.a.isin(df.a)]
Out[7]:
   a         b
0  2 -1.462567
1  3 -0.277680
2  4 -0.461539
3  5  1.094466
4  6 -1.086069
5  7  0.249207
6  8  2.613443
7  9  1.036450
```

Comment: The other columns have the similar naming 'keys' and so I actually want to maintain two separate data frames so I can plot the differences.